# How to replace/get value of parameter in MDX query passed by SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Sorry for very basic question,

I have SSRS report which takes value of parameter dynamically and creates MDX query.

Now, I have that MDX query and I want to run in SSMS or MDX studio. But I am not sure how to replace the parameter value.

For example:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[HC Threshold] AS Val(strtomember(@HC_Threshold).Name), FORMAT_STRING="$#,0"
```

And I found HC_Threshold dimension, which looks like

[image]

based on this, how do I modify 'Val(strtomember(@HC_Threshold).Name), FORMAT_STRING="$#,0"',  if user selects 75000.

Let me know if you need any more information, I am completely new with SSRS and Parameterized queries in MDX.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the parameter value for a string that produces a valid member of your dimension.

```
select [Product].[Model Name].[Model Name] on rows,
[Measures].[Sales Amount] on columns
from [Adventure Works DW2012]
where STRTOMEMBER("[Ship Date].[Calendar Quarter].[4]")
```

Note `STRTOMEMBER()` receives a string as argument and converts it to a valid member.

In your scenario it would be something like:

```
STRTOMEMBER("[HC_Threshold].[ID].[7500]")
```